# How to find matching elements from an array of objects using mongoDB query

Tags: arrays, database, mongodb, object, find

I want to find all elements matching product "bat". My structure for database is as follows

```
[
  {
    "key": 1,
    "productArray" : [
      {
         "requirementId": 5,
         "product": "bat"
      },
      {
        "requirementId": 6,
        "product": "Pen"
      },
     ]
  },
  {
    "key": 2
  },
  {
    "key": 3,
    "productArray": [
      {
        "requirementId": 1,
        "product": "bat"
      },
      {
        "requirementId": 2,
        "product": "Pen"
      },
      {
        "requirementId": 3,
        "product": "bat"
      },
      {
        "requirementId": 4,
        "product": "bat"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I have tried the following query but this query is returning only one matching element.

```
db.collection.find({"key": 3}, {"productArray": {"$elemMatch": { "product": "bat"}}})
```

result of above query is as follows

```
[
 {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"),
    "productArray": [
      {
        "product": "bat",
        "requirementId": 1
      }
    ]
 }
]
```

Can I get expected output for my problem is as follows using mongodb query Or should I use another approach for my case:

My expected output is as follows

```
[
  {
    "productArray": [
    {
      "requirementId": 1,
      "product": "bat"
    },
    {
      "requirementId": 3,
      "product": "bat"
    },
    {
      "requirementId": 4,
      "product": "bat"
    }
    ]
 }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you found, `$elemMatch` but also `$` are *lazy operators* and return the first element that matches.

You could add a pipeline in find (mongoDB 4.4+) but aggregation is better supported:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  $match: {
    key: 3
  }
},
{
  $project: {
    productArray: {
      "$filter": {
        "input": "$productArray",
        "as": "p",
        "cond": {
          $eq: [
            "$$p.product",
            "bat"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[Live version](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IdvuqRGP5L3)

Comment: Hello @minsky In this case I am getting all elements of an array I need only 3 of them

Comment: thanks for answer, please help more by telling how can i apply regex for matching string @minsky

Comment: @TusharKale replace "bat" for `/bat/i` to make it insensitive. Don't  do "/bat/i", just `/bat/i`

Comment: I mean if i search as "bA"  it should provide same result. I appreciate your answer @Minsky

Comment: @TusharKale asking how to write regular expressions is another question. The regex follows this syntax `/regexHere/`. This, should work though: `/ba[t]/i` or `/b[at]/i` depeding on how much flexibility you want.

Comment: @TusharKale if the solution worked please accept it. That's how the network works.